# Swift: How to make categories with UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parsing

I found this example which is what exactly I want. I am trying to make a table which the cells/sections collapse and expand. All the data in the parent cell and child cell are not fixed data which means I want to get them from web service (Parse). I was wondering how can I create one and what is the easiest solution to get me working with this.

[image: Cells are collapsed]

[image: Cells are expanded]

Comment: show me some code else post example link.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/Augustyniak/RATreeView).

Comment: Check this link - http://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/

Comment: @Mr.Bond I dont have any code and the app name is SIVVI on Appstore which I don't know if it will help.

Comment: @J.Wang Thats okay but its objective-C

Comment: @SumeetBajaj I will take a look at this, Thanks.

Comment: take a look, it's in Obj-C https://github.com/rob-nash/CollapsableTableKit it's same as you requirement.

Comment: @ArashAllahmorad Are you going to implement all these yourself? Can you use a library for that?

Comment: @J.Wang if using a library is easier then help me through it

Comment: @himanshupadia i can't understand objective-C :/

Comment: @ArashAllahmorad - here is link for swift - https://github.com/justinmfischer/SwiftyAccordionCells